# SQL replace values of two columns of all table from another table

Tags: sql

I have a table named `DEP` in `DGI` schema. This table is structured by different columns, and between them are the columns `DEPTO` and `RAMO`. I have another table which is basically a backup of the previous one, but with different data inside, and is it located in the same database but in another schema called `BKP`.

I need to replace values from `DGI.DEP` with `BKP.DEP`. However, I do not want to replace the whole table, just the `DEPTO` and `RAMO` columns.

I tried, but I get the error

> "Single-row subquery returns more than one row."

```
UPDATE DGI.EMPLEADO_DEP
SET (DEPTO, RAMO) = (
    SELECT B.DEPTO, B.RAMO
    FROM BKP.EMPLEADO_DEP B
    WHERE B.RFC = DGI.EMPLEADO_DEP.RFC
);
```

Comment: Could you please change this from all-caps into ordinary casing?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to adjust your question a little bit. Capital letters are the equivalent of shouting at people.

That aside, the issue may be with your syntax depending on which flavour of SQL you are using.

```
UPDATE E
SET E.DEPTO = B.DEPTO, E.RAMO = B.RAMO
FROM BKP.EMPLEADO_DEP B JOIN DGI.EMPLEADO_DEP E
WHERE B.RFC = E.RFC;
```

@nvogel makes a good point below, which is that we don't know which flavour of SQL you are using. It is possible that your BKP table has multiple instances of the same unique RFC found in the DGI table. Make sure that in both tables the RFC is unique.

As @nvogel was also kind enough to point out, the above type of query is usually constrained with a WHERE clause to ensure that only the data you want to be changed is changed (although in this case it does seem you want to update the entire column of data).

I would also recommend taking a simple backup of the DGI table in case the result is not what you wanted.

```
SELECT * INTO EMPLEADO_BACKUP from DGI.EMPLEADO_DEP
```

Comment: Andree's original syntax is correct in standard SQL and works in a number of DBMSs whereas the syntax you have used here is non-standard and specific to Microsoft. Although the syntax you have given is valid in MS SQL Server I definitely would recommend caution in this particular situation because this MSSQL syntax hides a potentially dangerous "feature", namely it updates all the rows even where the result is undefined. The results can be highly unpredictable. Test it very carefully before using it would be my advice!

Answer (score 0):

Check what are the keys of BKP.EMPLEADO_DEP. The error message you are getting suggests that the RFC column is not unique in that table, which means your query is not able to find one row that matches any given row in the other table. I'm guessing that what you intended to do is match the two tables on a key column or columns.

Alternatively take a look at the MERGE command.

If you need more help then please tell us which DBMS software you are using.